# Disabling/hiding customize option from ArcMap menu bar

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, customize-mode

[image]

I need disable or hide the *Customize* option. I have listen about a mxd file configuration, but isn't clear to me.

Is there any way?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on Customize > Customize Mode

[image]

When the window opens, just drag the Customize menu option from your toolbar.

[image]

Now the *Customize* option will be gone from your menubar.

[image]

To get it back you will need to open Customize Mode again, this time from a right-click on a toolbar > Customize (since you've removed the Customize menu). On the toolbars tab scroll down and find Main Menu and click the Reset button.

[image]

This will reset your Main Menu toolbar to restore any items you have removed from the default.

You can lock your modifications to these toolbars from the Customize window by adding a password.  Click on the Options tab and select Lock Customization

[image]

Enter and confirm a password

[image]

Now when you try to open the Customize window again (via Customize > Customize mode or via right-click > Customize) it will prompt for a password.

[image]

If the correct password is not entered, no customization can be made to the toolbars or menus.

Be aware you can restrict these customization and lock to the document or to ArcMap on the machine by checking or unchecking the "Save all customizations to the document" option on the Options tab.

Comment: You can then transport this to another workstation by copying the normal.mxt and overwriting each individual users' normal.mxt... you could even do that on a startup script. That would look a lot more professional than jumping onto each new users workstation before they start.

Comment: Michael, can you tell me how I can do that on a startup script?